# WinAPI - get a scrollable frame for drawing

Tags: c++, winapi, frame, scrollable

I am coding an algorithm that calculates sequencies through cooler bodies as an summer work. The algorithm itself is done and I started looking into making a simple GUI with C++ where you can create sequencies for specific combination of coolers and also to be able to view it beforehand. This isn't anything I have done before.

I have got something fairly simple to work and right now I draw how the sequencies look directly on the main window.
Whould it be any hard to instead draw it into a scrollable "frame" in the same main window?
Right now bigger combinations are too big to fit on the same screen, and just making the window bigger isn't enough.
Thanks for any help!

I tried making a static with style "WS_VSCROLL" and use "hdc = GetDC(hWndNewStatic)", which I got working with the draw for a small time, then it didn't work again. The scrollbar wasn't working.

[example program pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbwlU.png)

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    WNDCLASSEX wcex = {};
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDI_ICON));
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDI_ICON));
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("WinApp");
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("RegisterClassEx Failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        TEXT("WinApp"), TEXT("SeqGen"),
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("CreateWindow Failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Messages
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg))
        {}
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    LPCSTR moduleValue;
    static int index {};
    static unsigned module {0};
    static bool draw {false};

    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            hWndStatic = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("Static"), TEXT("Tube rows"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                30, 20, 100, 24,
                hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

            hWndStatic = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("Static"), TEXT("Water passes"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                130, 20, 100, 24,
                hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

            hWndStatic = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("Static"), TEXT("Multiples"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                230, 20, 100, 24,
                hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

            hWndrr = CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                30, 50, 50, 24,
                hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

            hWndvv = CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                130, 50, 50, 24,
                hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

            hWndN = CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("0"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                230, 50, 50, 24,
                hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

            hWndList = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("ListBox"), TEXT(""),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY,
                20, 150, TEXTBOX_WIDTH, TEXTBOX_HEIGHT,
                hWnd, (HMENU) LST_RESULT, NULL, NULL
            );


            hWndCreateall = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Create all DIR"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                50, 90, 100, 24,
                hWnd, (HMENU) BTN_CREATEALL, NULL, NULL
            );   

            hWndButton = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Create DIR"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                200, 90, 100, 24,
                hWnd, (HMENU) BTN_CREATE, NULL, NULL
            );   

            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (HIWORD(wParam))
            {
                case LBN_SELCHANGE:
                    if (LOWORD(wParam) == LST_RESULT)
                    {
                        index = SendMessage(hWndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

                        if (index >= 0)
                        {
                            module = 0;
                            moduleValue = (to_string(module).c_str());
                            SetWindowText(hWndStaticModule, moduleValue);
                            draw = true;
                            RedrawWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case BN_CLICKED:
                    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                    {
                        case BTN_CREATE:
                            --stuff for creating combination--

                            break;

                        case BTN_CREATEALL:
                            --stuff for creating all possible combination--

                            break;
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            if (draw)
            {
                --function for drawing stuff on main window--

                draw = false;
            }
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);

            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: TIP: I see you call UpdateWindow in response to WM_PAINT, you should avoid it since it generates a new WM_PAINT, also, in a win32 application, the hdc should be obtained in WM_PAINT. It is done with BeginPaint and after drawing it should be disposed with EndPaint.

Comment: [Custom Controls in Win32 API: Scrolling](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1042516/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Scrolling)

Comment: You can also embed more advanced controls like _FlowDocumentScrollViewer_ in which you can add anything inside : [Test  FlowDocumentScrollViewer](https://i.ibb.co/Xz0TQTH/Flow-Document-Scroll-Viewer.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You need a lot of code to achieve what you need, and I can only give you a theoretical explanation of the components needed.

1. **A panel class**. A panel needs its own window class with its very own windowproc. Panel proc should process `WM_VSCROLL`, and maybe `WM_HSCROLL`, *manually* setting the new scroll value with `SetScrollPos` and storing it in some state variable. Your `WM_*SCROLL` handler has now two options:

   - Call `InvalidateRect` and let WM_PAINT refresh the entire panel.
   - Call `ScrollWindow` to move the actual graphics around and then call `UpdateWindow` to refresh the uncovered area.
2. **A paint algorithim for panel**. You should react to `WM_PAINT` drawing your model like usual, but y coordinates must be shifted by the scroll state variable. You have a few options:

   - Redraw the entire window.
   - Draw the new window content on an off-screen HDC and then bitblit on the entire window.
   - Redraw the uncovered area (see previous point about `ScrollWindow`)
3. **An instance of the panel** on the main window. The main win will allocate the panel as child window like you do for the other controls, also specifying `WS_VSCROLL` (and `WS_HSCROLL`?) and configuring the scroll size with `SetScrollInfo`, according to the document size. Main win also need to react to `WM_SIZE` to resize (`MoveWindow`) the panel, giving it a new size. New size is calculated substracting a padding you like from the client area of the main win.

Every tiny bit will eventually need further Googling and posting on SO.

You may also consider drawing with OpenGL, DirectX, or just GDI+ (which in turn may open a whole lot of other questions).

Comment: Ok, I guessed it wouldn't be too easy.
I will look into this. Thanks a lot for the tips!

Comment: Glad you found it useful, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.